# Coloring td from inside the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

I print a table and in one of the td I need to style `="background-color:#000000"`
if the td value of `NAME` is null
else just to print the value.
Please show me how to do this without using `isNull` inside the td tag
AND if possible to color all the tr:

```
         function isNull(val) {
                 return (val == null) ? '' : val;
          }
    ...
    ...
      function paders(items) {
....
   $.each(items, function () {
                 ....                       
     vob += '<tr>' +
         '<td>' + if isNull(this.NAME) ..... + '</td>' +
```

Comment: Show the actual html. What is NAME ???

Comment: hi mplungjan!:) that inside the function i just eedited the Q

Comment: There is neither NAME nor VALUE on a table cell. Do you have an inputfield inside the cell? Can you SHOW THE TABLE CELL WITH CONTENT Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
vob += '<tr>' ;

if isNull(this.NAME) 

vob+='<td style="background:#000">' + value1+ '</td>'
else 
vob+='<td style="background:#fff">' + value2+ '</td>'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using jQuery

```
jQuery('td').each(function(i,elem){
if(elem.val() === null || elem.val() === "")
elem.css('background-color','#000000');
});
```

Comment: i understand your code but not sure how to use it - where do you put it?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a function for that like this

```
 function isNull(val) {
         return (val == null) ? '' : val;
  }

 function extendenTd(val) {
   if (isNull(val)) {
      return ' style ="background-color:#000000">';
   }
   return ">";
 }


vob += '<tr>' +
       '<td' + extendenTd(this.NAME)  ..... + '</td>' +
```

**hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fnGL7/

```
$(document).ready(function{
  $('input').each(function(i){
    var elem = $(this);
    if(elem.val() === null || elem.val() === "")
    elem.parent().parent().css('background-color','red');
  });
})

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="debit">Debit</label></td>
        <td>
            <input id="debit" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="credit">Credit</label></td>
        <td>
            <input id="credit" type="text" value="1000" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```